# C# Threading and events for pin pad device

Tags: c#, callback, delegates, event-handling, autoresetevent

I am new in C# and currently working on the backend code to support PIN pad. Basically, my code

```
OpenDevice() -> RequestPIN() 
-> key in PIN on PIN PAD -> GetResultPIN() 
-> ConsolePrintOutPIN() -> Print keyed PIN on the Console
```

I don't know how to write thread for this, so that once the "Enter key" is hit on the device after PIN, the system would automatically rolls to function `GetResultPIN()`. So, with my elementary knowledge, I wrote the following codes using `Console.ReadLine()` to separate each procedure:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // 1. Open PIN Pad device
        OpenDevice();

        Console.ReadLine();// to hold up from the previous procedure, it is *not* for input data purpose

        // 2. Request PIN from PIN Pad device.
        //    On the PIN Pad device, it reads:
        //    "Key in the PIN:     "
        RequestPIN();

        Console.ReadLine();// to hold up from the previous procedure, it is *not* for input data purpose

        // 3. get PIN from the device
        GetResultPIN();

        // 4. Print out on the Console 
        ConsolePrintOutPIN();

        Console.ReadLine();// to hold up from the previous procedure, it is *not* for input data purpose
    }
```

***Question:* Can anyone give me any suggestions on how to use threading/event/delegate that can avoid using `Console.ReadLine()`?**

As commended above, `Console.ReadLine()` is used just to stop the procedure (sorry about my naivety of using it this way....) Once I use `Console.ReadLine()`,   between `RequestPIN()` and `GetResult()`, the system would at least wait for me to Key in the PIN from the PIN PAD (connected to the computer through USB, **not** from key board), and then I would hit any key on the keyboard to pass `Console.ReadLine()` and `GetResultPIN()` would be able to get my PIN number from PIN Pad.....the whole program works now, it is not customer ready, because it is very choppy, doesn't flow due to `Console.ReadLine()` I added.....

So ideally, all the method would flow together. Once the device is opened, `RequestPIN()` should show on the PIN Pad screen asking for PIN number, some one can key in and hit enter on PIN Pad and it naturally flow to `GetResultPIN()` and read the result, and then it prints the PIN on the console...`

or

if the person doesn't key in PIN, the device would wait for 30s and directly goes to `GetResultPIN()` and print out "0000" on the Console

I have looked up treading and delegate, but am not sure how to use them in this situation.... Thank you!

***Reference:*** RequestPin() and GetResultPIN are listed down below:

```
mIPAD.requestPIN(waitTime, pinMsg, minLen, maxLen, tone, option, ",");
//This function wraps device command 0x04.  
//It directs the device to prompt the user to enter a PIN 
//by displaying one of five predetermined messages and playing
// a specified sound.  
//The messages on the device’s screen look like the figures below.  
//The event associated with this function is 
//OnPINRequestCompleteEvent.
```

*waitTime: Time the device should wait for the user to begin PIN entry*

*pinMsg: Message to display as a user prompt, such as "Enter PIN", "ReEnter PIN", "Verify PIN", etc*

*minLen and maxLen: minimum length and maximum length of PIN*

*tone: beeping tone option*

*Option: Verify PIN, not Verify PIN,  ISO0 FOrmat, ISO3 Format*

*Output would be: an integer, 0: Success, Non-Zero: Error*

```
    public void GetResultPIN()
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append(mIPAD.pin.KSN); 
               // Key Serial Number: 
               //a given number from the device, unique for each device
        sb.Append("," + mIPAD.pin.EPB);
               // EPB: encryption of PIN after Dubpt TripleDES,
               // essentially, EPB is PIN
        sb.Append("," + mIPAD.getStatusCode());
               //status code: Zero is good/done
               //             None-Zero is Error
        sb.Append("\r\n");
        result = sb.ToString();
    }
```

*Basically, the GetResultPIN() returns a string of random code, for example:
`9A00030000047A2000AB,AD781711481B08A2,0` when PIN is successful. If the pin-input part is skipped, it would return `,,0`.*

Comment: You need to assign the result of `Console.ReadLine();` - so something like `var pin = Console.ReadLine();` `pin` would then contain whatever was typed in.

Comment: Since we don't have any information on the API you are using, or what the functions `RequestPIN` and `getResultPIN` look like (although from what you typed, I can't imagine one function is camel cased while the other is pascal), its going to be impossible to answer this.

Comment: I just made my naming for consistent. Could you suggest what info that you need? I am happy to provide. Thank you!

Comment: Is `RequestPIN()` written by you?...or is it making a call to the hardware API?

Comment: Show us the source for `RequestPIN` and `GetResultPIN` functions please.

Comment: I updated my post by adding `RequestPIN()` and `GetResultPIN()`. `RequestPIN` is a function that goes with a dll library from our vendor, `GetRequestPIN()` is made myself. Thank you!

Comment: So the API has a "waitTime" parameter and a return value of success/failure.  You're saying that it doesn't **BLOCK** when you call it?  What are you passing in for a wait time?  Is that in seconds or milliseconds?  Just seems like it would have to block if it returns success/failure.

Comment: I am passing 10000 (assuming in ms) or 10 (assuming in s). It would not make a difference.... The function itself doesn't **block**. I also tried **Auto Reset Event** `static AutoResetEvent objAuto = new AutoResetEvent(false);`, `objAuto.WaitOne(20000);` between `RequestPIN` and `GetResult`, then it gives user a chance to key in the PIN, however, then it won't move on until 20 sec later.... I wonder whether there is a way say, either wait for 20 sec, or as soon as someone key in pin, whichever is shorter... You know what I mean? thx

Comment: With that new info, it seems like you could simply poll the result of `mIPAD.pin.EPB` in a loop with a small call to Thread.Sleep() to reduce CPU usage.

Comment: So Thread.Sleep() would hold up the thread from keeping going to give time for user to Key in the PIN right? What would "wake up" the thread though. How does the thread know that "Oh, the PIN is done for input" or "Oh, no one is keying the PIN, Time is up, report fail"?

Answer (score 2):

Really hard to know if this will work or not without hardware to play with...

This is the way I envisioned it working:

```
    static void Main()
    {
        OpenDevice();
        RequestPIN();
        if (GetResultPIN())
        {
            // do something with the PIN:
            var pin = mIPAD.pin.EPB;

            // ...

        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("0000");
        }
    }

    public static bool GetResultPIN()
    {
        TimeSpan timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
        System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch SW = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
        SW.Start();
        while (mIPAD.getStatusCode() != 0 && SW.Elapsed < timeout)
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50); // small call to prevent CPU usage ramping to 100%
        }
        return (mIPAD.getStatusCode() == 0);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can rewrite your api to:

- make `GetResultPIN()` return a value
- use this value as input for `ConsolePrintOutPIN()`

In `GetResultPIN` you need to make a Task To ReadYour Pin and wait for it.

See : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537610(v=vs.110).aspx

You can do something like this:

```
public string GetResultPIN()
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append(mIPAD.pin.KSN); 
           // Key Serial Number: 
           //a given number from the device, unique for each device
    sb.Append("," + mIPAD.pin.EPB);
           // EPB: encryption of PIN after Dubpt TripleDES,
           // essentially, EPB is PIN
    sb.Append("," + mIPAD.getStatusCode());
           //status code: Zero is good/done
           //             None-Zero is Error
    sb.Append("\r\n");
    Thread.Sleep(20*1000);  // it is in milliseconds
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for posting... The solution is still not ideal....
I also did some more testing regarding the function `RequestPIN()`. I have the following four scenarios:

1. User finishes keying in PIN sooner than the `waitTime` goes out. 

   `onPINRequestComplete : 
   OpStatus:0
   KSN:9A00030000047A2000C8
   EPB:39DED176D3EA40B9
   ..............................`
2. User doesn't finish keying in PIN when the `waitTime` is going out.

   `onPINRequestComplete : 
   OpStatus:2
   KSN:00000000000000000000
   EPB:0000000000000000
   ..............................`
3. User cancels the PIN pad option by pressing "Cancel X" key on the PIN Pad.

   `onPINRequestComplete : 
   OpStatus:1
   KSN:00000000000000000000
   EPB:0000000000000000
   ..............................`
4. User doesn't key in PIN at all during the waitTime, and then waitTime goes out.

   `onPINRequestComplete : 
   OpStatus:2
   KSN:00000000000000000000
   EPB:0000000000000000
   ..............................`

   So, scenario 1 and 3 would require the thread to wake up right away, while 2 and 4 would require the thread to wake up when the waiTime goes out. So using `Thread.sleep(20*1000)` within `GetResultPIN()` would work perfectly for scenario 2 and 4. As for 1 and 3, the user has to wait for a long time....

On the other hand, I found some code about `Event`

Within **Car.cs**:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WaitOnTasksToComplete
{
    class Car
    {
        public event Action OnChange;

        private double speed;
        public double Speed
        {
            get { return speed; }
            set { speed = value;
                if (speed >= 60)
                {
                    if (OnChange != null)
                    {
                        OnChange();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Within **Program.cs**:

```
using System;

namespace WaitOnTasksToComplete
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Car c = new Car();
            c.OnChange += C_OnChange;

            c.Speed = 5;
            c.Speed = 55;
            c.Speed = 65;
            c.Speed = 75;

        }

        private static void C_OnChange()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Event fired: Car goes higher than 60 MPH.");
        }
    }
}
```

So, basically once the `Car.speed` jumps above 60, the alarm would show. I am considering borrowing the condition into my situation: Initialize `OpStatus = -999`. When `OpStatus=0 or 1`, keep executing `GetResultPIN()` and `PrintMessagePIN()`. If `OpStatus=2 or others`, keep waiting...

That is just my thoughts.... still have no clue how to implement it.... Any related ideas or suggestions would be appreciated.....

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I figured out. I am basically using threading here. The main flow is `OpenDevice()->RequestPIN()->Thread(()=>CheckOpStatus(getResultPIN)) -> Thread.Start()`. Within the Thread,  a loop is set to check every half second what the `OpStatus` is. Per my previous post, `OpStatus`is the output parameter of PIN Pad, `zero- success; non-zero: failure`. That said, the loop would proceed until either `bool condition_WithinWaitTime` or `bool condition_NoKeyEvent` breaks. After breaking out, invoke the `getResultPIN` and so on....

Here is my source code, as PIN input is one of my functions, the rest of which have very similar behavior in terms programming (request->manual operation->feedback), so I also included a delegate variable to represents all functions (card swiping, PIN, signature bla bla).

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        OpenDevice();
        EventGetPIN();

    }
    static void EventGetPIN()
    {
        myDel getResult = new myDel(GetResultPIN);
        Thread thread1 = new Thread(() => CheckOpStatus(getResult));

        myDel requestDel = new myDel(RequestPIN); requestDel();
        thread1.Start();
    }
    static void CheckOpStatus(Delegate getResult)
    {
        int count = 0;
        int checkingPeriod = 500;
        int totalWaitTime = waitTime * 1000 + offsetTime;
        string OpStatus;
        string ksnStart = mIPAD.getKSN();
        string ksn = ksnStart;
        bool condition_WithinWaitTime = true;
        bool condition_NoKeyEvent = true;
        while (condition_WithinWaitTime & condition_NoKeyEvent)
        {
            count++;
            OpStatus = mIPAD.getStatusCode().ToString();
            ksn = mIPAD.getKSN();
            //Console.WriteLine(OpStatus);
            condition_WithinWaitTime = (count * checkingPeriod) < totalWaitTime;
            condition_NoKeyEvent = (ksn == ksnStart);
            Thread.Sleep(checkingPeriod);
        }

        getResult.DynamicInvoke();
    }
```