# C#: Using Pin Pad instead of a keyboard for input in a console Application

Tags: c#, .net, user-input, device

I am using **Visual Studio 2013**, **.NET 4.5**, **C#**, OS **Windows 8**.
I want to set a pin pad as only input device for my **Console** application in **C#**... Which library will be used...
[This guy is doing it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31662622/c-sharp-threading-and-events-for-pin-pad-device) but he only writes `opendevice()` and `RequestPin()` which not built in functions, whereas I need to know libraries and function. Are there any built in assemblies in **.NET** for that? Take a little time if possible and explain if anyone knows.... or point me in the right direction for research...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

namespace DisableOpt
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           Console.WriteLine("Enter Password:");
           string inputP = Console.ReadLine();
           if (inputP == "2517")
           {
              Console.Clear();

                Console.WriteLine("Press 1 to do to 1 ");
                Console.WriteLine("Press 2 to do to 2 ");
                Console.WriteLine("Press 3 to do to 3 ");
                Console.WriteLine("Press 4 to do to 4 ");
                Console.WriteLine("Press 9 to exit ");

                option = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            switch (option)
            {
                case 1:
                    Console.WriteLine("Something");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    Console.WriteLine("Something");
                    break;
                case 3:
                    Console.WriteLine("Something");
                    break;
                case 4:
                    Console.WriteLine("Something");
                    break;
                case 9:
                    Environment.Exit(0);
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("Selected Option Not Valid");
                    break;

                }

             }
             else 
             {
                Console.WriteLine("Wrong Password Application is exiting...");
                Thread.Sleep(3000);
                Environment.Exit(0);
              }
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: This entirely depends on the hardware you choose to use.  If you choose a pin-pad that emulates a keyboard you shouldn't need to do anything special at all.

Comment: tried the usual procedure... it doesn't take input... Keypad is general 13 button Encrypting Pin Pad with 0-9 digits and clear, cancel and enter button